# Find the closest div in Jquery table

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new en jQuery and I'm trying to build a simple tab responsive with jQuery. I know that this is a common question. But I cannot solve it at this time. Can you guide me on the good way. I don't know what is my error there. I've try with .closest, .parent, find but it's still not working.

```
<div class="sn_body_tab">
  <div class="sn_tab_title" id="sn_tab_title" >
    title 1
  </div>
  <div class="sn_tab_content" id="sn_tab_content">
    content 1
  </div>

  <div class="sn_tab_title">
    title 2
  </div>
  <div class="sn_tab_content" id="sn_tab_content">
    content 2
  </div>

  <div class="sn_tab_title">
    title 3
  </div>
  <div class="sn_tab_content" id="sn_tab_content">
    content 3
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#sn_tab_title').on('click', function (event) {
        $(this).closest('#sn_tab_content').slideToggle();
      });
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of you should never have multiple elements with the same id, in this case `sn_tab_content` use class for this.

Since `sn_tab_content` is AFTER `sn_tab_title` then you need to use `.next()` and not `closest()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sn_tab_title').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).next('.sn_tab_content').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sn_body_tab">
  <div class="sn_tab_title" id="sn_tab_title">
    title 1
  </div>
  <div class="sn_tab_content">
    content 1
  </div>

  <div class="sn_tab_title">
    title 2
  </div>
  <div class="sn_tab_content">
    content 2
  </div>

  <div class="sn_tab_title">
    title 3
  </div>
  <div class="sn_tab_content">
    content 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool thanks for your answer @Carsten !! It's exactly what I'm looking for. Sorry for this basic question, I'm a nerd !

Comment: @jacquesMesnet No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 1):

an id should be unique in entire HTML document. But you assigned same ids(sn_tab_title and sn_tab_content) to your divs.

**Try this**

```
<div class="sn_body_tab">
  <div class="sn_tab_title" >
    title 1
  </div>
  <div class="sn_tab_content">
    content 1
  </div>

  <div class="sn_tab_title">
    title 2
  </div>
  <div class="sn_tab_content">
    content 2
  </div>

  <div class="sn_tab_title">
    title 3
  </div>
  <div class="sn_tab_content">
    content 3
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.sn_tab_title').on('click', function (event) {
        $(this).closest('.sn_tab_content').slideToggle();
      });
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `next` instead of `closest` and use `class name like .sn_tab_title`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sn_tab_title').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).next('.sn_tab_content').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sn_tab_title').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).next('.sn_tab_content').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sn_body_tab">
  <div class="sn_tab_title">
    title 1
  </div>
  <div class="sn_tab_content">
    content 1
  </div>

  <div class="sn_tab_title">
    title 2
  </div>
  <div class="sn_tab_content">
    content 2
  </div>

  <div class="sn_tab_title">
    title 3
  </div>
  <div class="sn_tab_content">
    content 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: NEVER user the same ID multiple times

Comment: I didn't downvote you but i guess the person who did downvoted you because of you multiple duplicated id's

Comment: but i updated my answer and ids in questioner code thats why i put same

Comment: I can't tell who downvoted you, but downvoting me (noticed by your score) without leaving a comment about why is just not nice. ill upvote you because you corrected the mistakes.

Comment: i can also same for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158488/discussion-between-carsten-lovbo-andersen-and-bhargav).

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Bhargav, As i clearly said, I didn't downvote you, I upvoted you after you corrected the mistakes in your code. You risk the chance of getting a downvote if you have mistakes in your code.

Comment: i dont tell about that , i say i do same for upvote but now i vote is locked for you so i cant do upvote for you nothing else or dont missunderstand

Answer (score -1):

Try this hope this will helps you.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(".result").text($(".sn_body_tab").closest("sn_body_tab").find('div').text());
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sn_body_tab">
  <div class="sn_tab_title" id="sn_tab_title" >
    title 1
  </div>
  <div class="sn_tab_content" id="sn_tab_content">
    content 1
  </div>

  <div class="sn_tab_title">
    title 2
  </div>
  <div class="sn_tab_content" id="sn_tab_content">
    content 2
  </div>

  <div class="sn_tab_title">
    title 3
  </div>
  <div class="sn_tab_content" id="sn_tab_content">
    content 3
  </div>
</div>
<div class="result">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ?? Not realy related dude

Comment: How would this help the OP at all

Comment: Now check your output